# Login to a website through web-scraping tool in Python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, urllib2, web-scraping

I am  using Selenium webdriver in Python for a web-scraping project.

I would like to login by entering the login details and then click the submit button.

I am able to enter the Username and Password. But I am not able to mouseclick the submit button.

The "submit" button is of type `<input>`.

```
<input type="image" src="/images/buttons/loginnow.gif" tabindex="3">
```

Here is the python code where I am trying to click the mouse.

```
submitButton=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='image'][@src='/images/buttons/loginnow.gif']")
driver.click(submitButton)
```

I get the following error :

> AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'click'

Any idea how to fix it or any other alternative solution to login to a website in Python.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call the click function of the element, not the driver.

```
submitButton=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='image'][@src='/images/buttons/loginnow.gif']")
submitButton.click()
```

Answer (score 9):

I had good luck using `mechanize`. It's pretty straightforward and simple to use.

Here's a stripped-down version of a script I made:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from tidylib import tidy_document

import mechanize
import cookielib

if __name__ == '__main__':
  browser = mechanize.Browser()

  cookiejar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
  browser.set_cookiejar(cookiejar)

  browser.set_handle_equiv(True)
  browser.set_handle_redirect(True)
  browser.set_handle_referer(True)
  browser.set_handle_robots(False)

  browser.open('https://www.example.com/')

  browser.select_form(name = 'loginform')
  browser['username'] = 'foo'
  browser['password'] = 'bar'

  browser.submit()

  browser.open(browser.click_link(text = 'Link text'))

  soup = BeautifulSoup(tidy_document(browser.response().read())[0])
```

You don't need to click on the image, really. You just need to fill out all the appropriate form details and just `submit()` it.

Also, if you won't be parsing anything, just get rid of the `BeautifulSoup` and `tidylib` dependencies.

Comment: Vow.. This is amazing really, As it turns out, Selenium also has `submit()` which worked for me

Comment: That's even better that rewriting your script :P